# Nested if drop to parent else

Tags: c++

Maybe I'm just being stupid but how could something like this "goto parentelse" be accomplished (I'm using c++):

```
if (Something)
{ 
    if (AnotherThingDependentOnSomething)
    {
        certain stuff
    }
    else
    {
        <goto parentelse>
    }
}
else
{
    other stuff
}
```

AnotherThingDependentOnSomething cannot be evaluated unless something is true.
I need to do other stuff before running that test.
So my question is about going to the parent else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your needs right, then maybe having a little success flag makes the code more readable:

```
bool complicated_condition_holds = false;

if (Something)
{
  // laborious stuff...

  if (SomethingElse)
  {
    // tedious stuff...

    complicated_condition_holds = true;
  }
}

if (!complicated_condition_holds)
{
  // your original "else" block
}
```

Comment: Ja, this is what I'm talking about - cleanest I've seen. I was just hoping for some kind of "drop to parent else" solution like "break" or something

Comment: I like this one. Though I would arrange my flags differently.

Comment: @j3: Nah... conditionals aren't loops, so there's no notion of "parent" like that.

Answer (score 3):

In situations like this its better to write simpler, easier to understand code.  Maintenance will be harder (and buggier) if you try and be clever.

```
bool another_thing = false;

bool some_thing = Something(); // Side effects were implied?

if (some_thing) {
  // ... code dependent on something, but before another thing
  if (AnotherThingDependentOnSomething) {
    another_thing = true;
    // ...
  }
}

if (!some_thing || another_thing) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: True, and I think this is what I'll have to go with. Pity your solution is not the one with the votes...

Comment: @j3frea : The votes don't matter. Pick the answer that best suits your needs.

Comment: You'll be "evaluating" (Something) twice. If that's not what you want, then pull it out and store it at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

How about just taking out the else statement?

```
if (Something)
{
     //Do some stuff 
    if (AnotherThingDependentOnSomething)
    {
        certain stuff
    }
}
else
{
    other stuff
}
```

EDIT:

OK, I think I understand what you want to do know.  What I would recommend is this:

```
void OtherStuff()
{
    //Other stuff
}

void CurrentFunction()
{
    if(Something)
    {
        //Do some stuff
        if(AnotherThingDependentOnSomething)
        {
            //certain stuff
        }
        else
        {
            OtherStuff();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        OtherStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't evaluate the else statement if AnotherThingDependentOnSomething is false (because Something is true)

Comment: @j3frea: What exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: If the text in textbox is greater than a certain length and it has reached this point of the method, it could have been pasted so I generate a list of possible options and see if there are any. If either of those fail (certain length is too short or there aren't options), I need to do something else

Comment: @j3frea: I meant where in your code are you trying to go? Does the change that I made do what you want?

Comment: @j3frea: I would disagree that Tom's is better.  In general if you have repeated code, it is good to put it in some function.

Comment: except that functions are cumbersome and the code is associated with the rest of the if statement so for readability it's better to have it all together. I didn't downvote you (your first solution deserved it though). The change does what I wanted as I said before.

Comment: @j3frea: It's hard to come up with a good solution when the question is very ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor out the common part then call it from both places.

```
if (Something)
{
    // do some stuff before the nested if

    if (AnotherThingDependentOnSomething)
    {
        certain stuff
    }
    else doOtherStuff();
}
else
{
    doOtherStuff();
}

void doOtherStuff(params...?)
{
    other stuff
}
```